# Mapping querystring value as controller in route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have website that shows user submitted content in 30+ languages in front page,I am currently using paths like:

```
http://www.example.com?lang=en
```

or if it's not first page

```
 http://www.example.com?lang=en&page=2
```

But that really isn't user or seo friendly.
Is there a way in mvc to route these values to something like

```
 http://www.example.com/en
```

and

```
 http://www.example.com/en/2
```

without adding new action in-between like in this case `lang`:

`http://www.example.com/lang/en/2`

**Update. Here is what I came up from Alexeis answer, in case anybody will need same thing:**

In case of just language:

```
 routes.MapRoute("MyLang", "{lang}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },new { lang = @"\D{2}"});
```

In case you need language and optionally page:

```
   routes.MapRoute("MyLang", "{lang}/{page}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }, new { lang = @"\D{2}", page = @"\d+"});
```

It should not catch any other paths unless you have Actions with only 2 letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need "lang/" for the route to match culture. Simple "{lang}" will do as long as you order routes in a way so other routes are matched correctly. You may also consider [constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs) on routing parameters to limit number of conflicts.

```
routes.MapRoute("MyLang", "{lang}",
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Home",  }

class HomeController{
  public ActionResult Home(string lang)
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can add a new route like this

```
routes.MapRoute("MyLang", "{action}/{page}",
     new { controller = "ControllerName",page=0 }
```

this way the lang name will automatically be mapped to the action and page will be passed as a parameter provided u have action signature as

```
public ActionResult English(int page)
```

obsly the return type and action name can be changed